# How to set this if isset function

Tags: php, html

I have the following code that sets a background if user has uploaded to database. If user has NOT uploaded an image then the result is a blank img src=''

I need to set this as an if isset function so I can plug in an alternate image if user has not uploaded anything.

Here is the current code:

```
<div id="background"><?php echo isset($background_image) && file_exists(ROOT.$background_image)?"<img src='$background_image' alt='' />":'';?></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code's a little dirty, opening php and closing it mid-html tag is only going to make it confusing for you in the future.

You're echoing back an isset which is just echo'ing back a boolean.

Try this;

```
$background_image = ""; // Not sure what you're using here - their username? Dump it in here anyway.
if (file_exists($background_image))
{
    echo "  <div id=\"background\">
            <img src=\"{$background_image}\" alt=\"\" title=\"\" />
        </div>";
}
```

Hope this helps.

- Eoghan

Comment: Thanks Eoghan that worked! And thanks to everyone else for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but a another aproach to what you are trying to do would be:

```
<div id="background">
<?php 
$optionalImage = 'background.png';
$userImage = getUserImage();
if(empty($userImage)) {
    $userImage = $optionalImage;
}
?>
<img src="<?php echo $userImage; ?>" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it really neccessary to set the blank source of the image?

But a understandable and corrected code of what you are attempting is this

```
<div id="background">

    <?php
    echo "<img src='"; 
        echo isset($background_image) && file_exists(ROOT.$background_image) ? $background_image : '';
    echo "' alt='' />";
    ?>

</div>
```

The problem was that, either you were `echo` entire `<img>` tag, or just display `' '`(Blank) with attached endings.

The short form:

```
    echo "<img src='".(isset($background_image) && file_exists(ROOT.$background_image) ? $background_image : '')."' alt='' />";
```